# Autohotkey - Enable all mouse click functionality and also play a sound

Tags: autohotkey

I have this autohotkey script, I want to play a sound on mouse click. But this script doesn't let me drag windows or resize window or highlighting text  using mouse left click.

Any idea how I can have all mouse left click functionality and also play the `Error.wav` sound on every click?

```
LButton::
MouseClick, Left
SoundPlay, C:\Windows\media\Error.wav
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current script is not only listening for a mouse click, but also emulating a second click with `MouseClick, Left`. It seems that's not what you want. Also use `~` to ensure that

> When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked
> (hidden from the system)

```
~LButton::SoundPlay, C:\Windows\media\Error.wav
```

See [Hotkeys documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Comment: what would be the `LButton` equivalent of double click.. that is play another sound when we double click.

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/59816-double-click-as-hotkey/